# UI: Text box with multiple lines

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I want to incorporate in my Blender interface (in my addon) a text box that allows you to write notes on several lines (as in the text editor script). Currently, what I find in Blender are text boxes on one line!

Answer (score 5):

As far as i understand there is currently no way to have multiline text boxes. However there is a solution in work which will allow multi line tool tips:

https://developer.blender.org/D622

From the comments i think that this patch will also allow multiline text boxes as a side effect.

Comment: thank you for your response. Too bad it does not exist in Blender. This can be useful when you want to annotate objects (in collaborative work) in architecture, CAD ...

Comment: Looks like multi-line text boxes are coming in Blender 2.8: https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:2.8/UI/Workshop_Writeup/#Widgets